# How to make a custom Linked List using IEnumerable, IEnumerator

Tags: c#, linked-list, ienumerable, ienumerator

I'm trying to create a simple Linked List that allows me to iterate each element.

But when I try to iterate the list on the method GetReservation() the foreach imidiatly stops and I don't understand why.

I supose that 'this' instruction returns the Enumerable part of the class.

But I'm not sure.

I need some help to figure it out.

```
public class Reservation
    {
        public string reference;
        public string client;
        public string state;



        public Reservation(string reference, string client, string state)
        {
            this.reference = reference;
            this.client = client;
            this.state = state;
        }

        public Reservation()
        {
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Reservation reservation &&
                   reference == reservation.reference &&
                   client == reservation.client &&
                   state == reservation.state;
        }


    }
```

```
public class Row
    {
        public Reservation reservation;
        public Row nextRow;

    }
```

```
public class Lista : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
    {
        private Row _header;
        private Row Current;
        private int counter;

        public Lista()
        {
            _header = Current = null;
            counter = 0;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (Current.nextRow != null)
            {
                Current = Current.nextRow;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Current = _header;
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return Current;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public void Add(Reservation data)
        {
            Row newRow = new Row();
            newRow.reservation = data;
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                _header = Current = newRow;
            } else
            {
                Current.nextRow = newRow;
                Current = newRow;
            }
            counter++;
        }

        public Reservation GetReservation(int index)
        {
            int x = 0;

            foreach (Row row in this)
            {
                if (x == index)
                {
                    return row.reservation;
                }
                x++;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public Reservation Remove(Reservation data)
        {
            Reservation reservation = null;
            if (_header.reservation.Equals(data)){
                reservation = _header.reservation;
                _header = _header.nextRow;
            } else
            {
                foreach (Row row in this)
                {
                    if (row.nextRow.reservation.Equals(data))
                    {
                        if(row.nextRow.nextRow == null)
                        {
                            reservation = row.nextRow.reservation;
                            row.nextRow = null;
                        } else
                        {
                            reservation = row.nextRow.reservation;
                            row.nextRow = row.nextRow.nextRow;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (reservation != null)
            {
                counter--;
            }

            return reservation;
            
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's probably nothing in your list. Put a breakpoint at the foreach and see what value this has.

Comment: I would *strongly* discourage you from having an IEnumerable that mutates the underlying collection when iterated, as you are doing.  You shoiuld also ensure that every enumerator returned by GetEnumerable is able to be an *independent* enumerator.  Always returning the same one means they'll each affect the other, which you don't want.  You should generally rely on iterator blocks to implement custom IEnumerables, rather than doing it all by hand.  It's pretty rare to need features an iterator block doesn't provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that both the linked list and the enumerator share the current row for different purposes.

When the `Add` method is called, `Current` is set to the new row which is the last item of the linked list.

The `foreach` block in `GetReservation` calls `GetEnumerator` which returns the instance of this list. But the current row of the list is the last added row. So when `MoveNext` is called during the iteration, `false` is returned since the last row has no next row. That ends the loop.

To solve this problem it is best to create a separate class which implements `IEnumerator` e.g.

```
public class Lista : IEnumerable
{
    ...

    GetEnumerator() 
    {
        return new ListaEnumerator(_header);
    }

    private class ListaEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        private Row _current;

        public ListaEnumerator(Row header)
        {
            _current = header;
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

This way it is possible to have several enumerators that do not affect each other or the list.

Comment: I agree w/ your observation of using `Current`. However, I argue the main issue is a Single Responsibility Principle violation by combining the `IEnumerator` implementation with the class (collection) to be enumerated. Misusing `Current` would  never would happen if the `IEnumerator` was a separate class.

Comment: I suspect `IEnumerator.position` property is not needed. By definition Linked List items are iterated via node links (` nextRow`) and by design cannot be accessed like array elements.  Said another way, sequential access vice random access.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need the `IEnumerable` implementation to return a new instance of a new class `ListEnumerator : IEnumerator`such that `ListEnumerator` will have `Current` so different instances of `ListEnumerator` can iterate the list instance independently.
2. You better of implementing generic versions e.g. `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`

Usually the `IEnumerator` implementation is a private class nested under the `IEnumerable` implementation and it has a data member pointing to the instance of `IEnumerable` implementation which is being iterated.